# Extract Youtube video id from URL parameter?

Tags: jquery, parameters, youtube

For example if the youtube video is `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hTPDG0fGCU` and my website is `http://mysite.com?youtubeurl=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hTPDG0fGCU` then set the id in this case `6hTPDG0fGCU` as `var youtubevideoid`
something i have working atm but only for replacing an iframe src.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(main);

function main()
{
 $('iframe').attr('src', getIframeUrl() );
 registerEvents();
 resizeIframe();
}

function getIframeUrl()
{
 var url = window.location.href;
 var iframe_url = 'http://lowkeyunofficial.blogspot.com/';
 var param_start = url.indexOf("iframe=");
 if( param_start != -1 )
  iframe_url = url.substr(param_start+7,url.length-param_start-7);
 if( iframe_url.indexOf("http://") == -1)
  iframe_url = "http://" + iframe_url ;

 return iframe_url;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using a regular expression:

```
var url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=26PAgklYYvo&ob=av3e";
var video_id = url.match(/v=(.{11})/)[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Could always use regex for something like this, just as an example:

```
var url = "http://mysite.com?youtubeurl=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hTPDG0fGCU",
     id = url.match(/\?v=([^&]*)/)[1];
```

P.S. Sorry @Alex, for some reason the answer notice didn't pop up.  If the id is truly always 11 chars long, that regex is better.

Comment: Looks like it: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/js_api_reference.html#GettingStarted